# Occasional trouble idling

Tags: fuel-system, subaru, idle, forester, intermittent-problems

I have a 2004 Subaru Forester XS (manual transmission).  A few times a month, the engine will not start or idle without feathering the accelerator.  During normal driving, everything works fine until I press the clutch in or put the car in neutral.  It feels like there just isn't enough fuel being fed into the engine.  Most of the time, though, I have no issues.  This issue has appeared and disappeared for a couple of years now.  It happens in hot summer weather and in the dead of winter.  It happens when the car has been sitting for a day or two, and it happens while I'm out and about.

I pulled out and cleaned the idle air control valve as well as the air intake system.  I have used a couple different kinds of fuel injector cleaner.  I checked for vacuum leaks.  The timing belt was changed recently, and they checked the fuel pump while they were in there and said it was fine.

Any ideas?  Maybe something I should double-check or test more thoroughly?  It is more of a minor inconvenience than a catastrophic issue, which is why after a couple of years, I still haven't fixed the issue.  Whenever it happens, I just give it some gas as I'm starting it and when the engine isn't in gear, and it works fine.

Comment: Have you replaced the fuel filter? I assume since you didn't mention it that the car isn't throwing any codes when this happens?

Comment: I haven't checked the filter.  I'll do that this afternoon.  And no, there are no codes or anything coming up.

Comment: Would it be possible to get us the fuel trims as well? You should be able to get them if you have access to an OBDII reader

Comment: Re-re-reading your question, I believe this is the most important sentence that I somehow kept glossing over: "everything works fine until I press the clutch in or put the car in neutral." This means that intermittently when the car recieves the signal to return to idle, the problem occurs. This re-re-validates my confidence in the fuel filter suggestion and the rest of @Zaid's answer.

Comment: I was going to check the filter yesterday, but I didn't get a chance.  When I have some time tomorrow, I'll open the hood and see what shape it's in.  I'll report back when I have more info.

Comment: Make the computer re-learn idle strategy, first clean the throttle body, then disconnect battery for 15 min, re-connect battery and start the vehicle with all accy off, do not touch anything and let idle for 15 min, then turn on ac on high and let sit for another 15 min undisturbed so the computer can re-learn idle strategy.

Answer (score 3):

### Why would the car stumble occasionally?

Based on what's been described, I'd say it's probably because the air-fuel mixture isn't right. It's either running too rich or too lean.

- If it is running lean enough, you should be able to hear the engine ping/"cough".
- Too rich, and the engine will feel like it's getting bogged down.

Depressing the clutch or shifting to neutral acts as a near-instantaneous load reduction on the engine, which changes the amount of air flowing into the cylinders. If the fuel management doesn't keep up, it is very easy for the air-fuel ratio to go beyond the engine's intended range of operation.

### Possible culprits

- ***an under-reading MAF sensor***

  positive fuel trims would indicate that this is a plausible root cause.

  If you're confident that there are no vacuum leaks, MAF's can give lower-than-expected measurements over time due to fouling of the sensor.

  Cleaning the MAF sensor with electronic cleaner may help restore the sensor's functionality. Bear in mind that a clogged air filter can also cause this.
- ***insufficient fuel pressure***

  Again, a positive fuel trim would corroborate this possibility.

  You've said that the fuel pump was deemed to be fine, but there are other players on the fuel side of the engine. MooseLucifer suggested a clogged fuel filter, and a malfunctioning fuel pressure regulator can also do this.

  You would need to measure fuel rail pressure to narrow down possible reasons in this category.
- ***too much fuel pressure***

  This root cause would be evidenced by a negative fuel trim.

  One reason for this would be a malfunctioning fuel pressure regulator.
- ***lazy lambda feedback***

  If an O2 sensor is not able to keep up with what the actual AFR's are, the fuel management will not be able to keep up with changing loads.

  This one is less likely given that you intermittently face issues even when starting the vehicle, when open-loop mode is active.

Comment: Not disagreeing, as I'm still stumped - Which of these would only cause the engine to stumble when the clutch is depressed and not when it is engaged in neutral, all without throwing a code?

Comment: @MooseLucifer if I understand correctly the OP's problem is that it just won't idle sometimes, regardless of clutch position. Opening the throttle a bit prevents stalling.

Comment: @Zaid I'm interested in the "Bear in mind that a clogged air filter can also cause this". Could you explain how a clogged filter can cause MAF underreading?

Comment: @Zaid also about the insufficient fuel pressure part. If the fuel pressure is reduced by a weak pump or clogged filter, shouldn't problems arise under hard load when fuel pressure provided becomes insufficient for the airflow, rather than idle?

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing a clogged air filter will have a greater pressure drop across it. This means the engine would be consuming less air. If the air filter is clogged enough, the resultant air-fuel mixture could be too rich for fuel management to rectify, resulting in sputtering/stalling. Regarding your suggestion about insufficient fuel pressure, the way I read the question the sputtering is not happening at stable idle, but sudden load reduction.

Comment: @Zaid Please don't take these as suggestions, I would just like to understand your reasoning. I can't understand how a clogged air filter can affect the fuel mixture, as on petrol engines fuel mixture is determined by the MAF/MAP readings. If the mass/pressure is reduced by the greater pressure drop, the ECU should still calculate a proper amount of fuel to retain the correct mixture, no?

Comment: @Zaid The way I understood the question is that the car drives fine but simply won't stay at idle sometimes without throttle input. I guess clarification is needed.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing bear in mind that there is a limit to how much AFR correction the fuel management can make. Given that the vehicle runs most of the time, the correction (if any) seems to be sufficient under normal circumstances. But under sudden load drop, the ability to correct is no longer adequate, which is why the engine starts to sputter/stall. At least that's my reasoning.

Comment: @Zaid Are you talking about the fuel trim corrections? I am talking solely about calculating the fuel output before making adjustments here - injector opening times. What I'm trying to say is that if the filter is clogged and the air input is decreased, the ECU should be easily able to handle it without making lambda corrections if the MAF/MAP works well. A clogged filter should work the same as a throttle plate that's opened less, no?

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing what I said regarding limit holds true regardless of pre- or post-fuel trim correction. Injector pulsewidth will have to remain within a lower bound and an upper bound.

Comment: @Zaid Well, yes, but if pulsewidth is determined by measured airflow, why would a clogged filter (which simply reduces airflow) result in an out of bounds AFR?

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing because it could result in an air flow so low that even the minimum possible injector pulsewidth is too much

Comment: @Zaid I guess that's possible. Does it happen, though? How bad does the filter have to be?

Comment: I've ordered an OBDII sensor to check fuel trims.  I'll see if I can get any more insight from those.  The air filter is also in great shape.  But I'm pretty sure my Forester has a MAP sensor, not a MAF sensor.  Does that need to be pulled out and cleaned?  I know if operates a little differently than the MAF sensor.